# Text enhancing in image using python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have an image in which text is lighter and not clearly visible, i want to enhance the text and lighten then background using python pil or cv2. Help is needed. I needed to print this image and hence it has ro be clearer.

what i have done till now is below

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
im = Image.open('t.jpg')  
im2 = im.point(lambda p:p * 0.8)    
im2.save('t1.jpg')
```

Above has slightly darken the text but still i needed to make text clear and background whiter or lighter.
The image is a photo of a printed document with text colour in black on white paper but that is not clearly visible. Below is snap of photo
[image]

[image]

In image above behind and surrounding letters and words there is some kind of noise white and silver dots.
How can i completely remove them so that text borders can be clearly visible.

I have also inverted image colours and given below sample
[image]

I have tried following
Adaptive thresolding ,(failed)
Otsu method, (failed)
Gaussian blurring, (failed)
Colour segmentation, (failed)
Connected component removal (failed)
Denoising( failed because it also removed text)
but nothing worked. Above all methods made it even worse because result of above methods gave me below image. Also text is affected when connected compoment method is used
[image]

Please help is needed.

Also tried image magick morphology editing but failed
How actually noise exist is shown in below image. It is continous rectangle bar filled with dots surrounding text
![enter image description here
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMHim.jpg)!

Comment: Try adaptive thresholding

Answer (score 0):

Use [image thresholding](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)

You can use this example as well

```py
from PIL import Image  
  
# creating a object  
im = Image.open(r"t.jpg").convert('LA')
  
# using point function 
threshold = 191  # range from 0 to 255
im = im.point(lambda p: p >value threshold and 255) 
im.show()
```

Comment: If you are struggling with this code see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68957790

Answer (score 0):

You can use denoising

```
img = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21)
```

and then convert the image to grayscale

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

then dilate the image

```
kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

The result

[image]

You can further explore on threshold to get better result

Answer (score 0):

You can use Otsu binary thresholding:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output:

[image]